# Number conversion with decimal

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to convert the following numbers

```
0.065000
1.000000
```

to

```
0.065
1
```

Thanks.

Comment: convert how? for permanent storage in the "short" form, or for display at retrieval time?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
declare @val sql_variant,@i sql_variant
set @val=0.065000
select @i=SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@val, 'Scale') 
select (cast(@val as float) * power(10 , cast(@i as int)) )/ power(10 , cast(@i as int))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just typecast it to a number type.

```
SELECT CAST(YourField AS NUMERIC(18,14))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: That will cast it to `numeric(18,0)` which will change `0.065` to `0`.

Comment: Hmm..you are correct. Just corrected and added precision.

Comment: Now it won't remove the trailing zeroes as asked.

Comment: It looks as though SQL Fiddle removes trailing zeroes for display automatically. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3091/20 Presumably the OP is using another SQL Client that doesn't or there would be no need for the question. In management studio this would display at 14 decimal places and add trailing zeroes.

Comment: No, leading and trailing zeros don't matter for number types(numeric, decimal, int etc.). I am assuming his number is stored in char/varchar etc. type field. Thats the only way to preserve those zeros.

Comment: Hi Pradeep,

I ran your query:

select '0.065000', CAST('0.065000' AS numeric(18,14))
UNION ALL
select '1.000000', CAST('1.000000' AS numeric(18,14))

This is what I got:

0.065000      0.06500000000000
1.000000      1.00000000000000

Comment: You are probably missing something. The sqlfiddle link just above your comment has exactly the same query and gives the expected result.